# What is the difference between "With UnModified Version" & "With Workspace version"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In TFS I'm performing the following action.

UnShelve Pending Changes-->  right click a file in a ShelveSet --> select Compare --> There are three choices:

1. With Unmodified Version
2. With Work-space version
3. With Latest version

What is the difference between 1 and 2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the options are broken down as follows :

- **With Unmodified Version** - *The Shelve File will compare the files with any pending changes to the corresponding files prior to the shelve being created.*
- **With Work-Space Version** - *Typically this will compare your current code running on your machine to the code at the time that you checked out the file. Basically allowing you to see what changes you have made in the current checkout.*
- **With Latest Version** - *Compares your code to the most recent code that has been checked into TFS.*

So the difference between the first and second options would be that with the Unmodified choice, you would be comparing with any changes that occurred prior to the shelve being created and your work-space choice would display the changes that you had made in the current checkout.

Comment: Thank you Rion for explaning these points.

Could you pleae elaborate the  explanation more.

e.g. I have checked-out a file   MyFile.cs

I created a function  f1(); and created a shelve set.

Meanwhile my team members have checked-in more code in the same file. say  fn2() and fn3();


Now if I select "With Unmodified Version" ,  difference will show f1();

Now if I select "With Work-Space Version " what it will show?

or what arrangement should I do to understand the difference more clearly?

Comment: @harish At that point "With Workspace Version" would show the same thing as "With Unmodified Version", until you got latest. After getting latest the Workspace Version compare would show fn2() and fn3() being added, which is also what "With Latest Version" would show (since getting latest brings your workspace version up to the latest version). If a team member then checked in fn4(), then Unmodified would show fn1(), Workspace would show fn2() and fn3(), and Latest would show fn4() being added.